# How to use cloud init to change any file

Tags: azure, immutability, packer, cloud-init

I am new to cloud init, and i am wondering if cloud init lets you change a file variable at the boot time?

Basically suppose I have a file sitting on a VM image on the cloud as follows

```
This is a {{variable_for_day}}
```

Now I am wondering if it's possible to pass a list of values from cloud-init to update this variable *{{variable_for_day}}*

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the exact direction of variable flow you need. Here are your options:

1. Write **to** file - [write-files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files) to change the file during boot.
2. Extract **from** file - [runcmd/bootcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot) to extract the value from file, eg. into environment variable. I've used this in conjunction with [write-files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files) where I've had a somewhat complicated script that allowed me customizing my deployment - variable service endpoint, etc.

That being said, I've noticed `packer` tag. Describing your use-case with more pinpointed questions will be beneficial.

PS. No such thing as `immutability`, just lack of know-how ;)